# How to handle "and" and "in" within a case sql

Tags: sql

This is what my case is (within the SQL).  I receive the error:

> **Incorrect syntax near 'I'.**

How do I handle this?

```
,case
when UserType like 'Teacher/Instructor and Type like 'I have a student currently in a School' then 'Ok'
else 'General'
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
,case when UserType like '%Teacher/Instructor%' and Type like 
'%I have a student currently in a School%' then 'Ok' else 'General' end
```

Check the syntax for [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) and [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quote and the keyword `END`:

```
case when UserType like 'Teacher/Instructor'
     and Type like 'I have a student currently in a School'
 then 'Ok' 
 else 'General' 
end
```

Apart from that: `LIKE` is for wildcard comparision, such as `col LIKE 'Ab%'`. If you don't use any wildcard as in `col LIKE 'Ab'`, then you should use a simple `=` instead: `col = 'Ab'`. Don't tell the DBMS that it has to do a pattern matching when you are only looking for equality.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

1. You are missing the closing quote after "Instructor"
2. You are missing the `end` keyword after the `else` clause

To sum it up:

```
case
when UserType like 'Teacher/Instructor' and
-- Issue #1 here ---------------------^
 Type like 'I have a student currently in a School' then 'Ok'
else 'General'
end -- Issue #2 here
```